# How to change .c or .bmp to .ttf

Tags: fonts, bmp, truetype

Due to my ignorance, I created my lovely font for unicode characters using BitFontCreator. I planned to use it for text outputted on WinApi. After long period of production, I discovered that it can only export .c, .bin, and .bmp file. But these are not font file usable for WinApi, I am forced to use PutPixel function, but it is too slow to output! What am I supposed to do? I come up with one solution: change .c or .bmp to .ttf, but how ?(Is there other way?) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't, bitfontcreator is a bitmap font maker, which is really just a bitmap drawing that has nothing to do with "Fonts" until you load the image into a program that can slice it up into meaningful "letter 'W' is found at x/y/w/h values: ....".

OpenType fonts on the other hand (of which TTF is one of the two internal flavours) is a vector outline real font format (in that it has an authoritative and exhaustive specification), and is pretty much one of the most complex pieces of software in existence =)

What you *can* do is import each letter into a program that can do vector abstraction when importing a bitmap for a letter, like HighLogic's [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html), so you end up with vector approximations of your bitmaps. You'll then spend a fair amount of time fixing the abstraction mistakes, but at least you'll have an actual modern font after that.

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert your pixel data to a "real" font. PutPixel is horrendously slow and should not be used for such a purpose.

A half-way solution is to put each of your characters into a single bitmap and draw these instead.

A full, fast solution is to grab the window in a bitmap, draw your characters into it, and draw the modified bitmap in your window again. That can be done with the full window (if you need to fully redraw all text) or with a finer granulariy, such as one line at a time.